# How to add Reflection for UNIX and OpenVMS reference to C#?

Tags: c#, unix, reflection, openvms

I am trying to add a reference to `Reflection for UNIX and OpenVMS` to my C# project but get the following error

`A reference to 'Reflection for UNIX and OpenVMS' could not be added`

[image]

Does this mean I do not have that library ? Why would it show up then ? Can I download it and then reference ? I could not find the libraries on their [website](http://support.attachmate.com/techdocs/2271.html) .

Comment: VS will also reject it if it cannot convert the type library without any minor mishaps.  Or big mishaps.  You'll have to use Tlbimp.exe instead to see the issues.

Answer (score 1):

Confirm the correct path to the library you are trying to add. Perhaps something went wrong there.

Another option would be to right click on the project and go to property pages. 
Add the reference from there.

I was unable to add a reference earlier today. It worked after adding it from the Property Pages option...

Good Luck...

Comment: I should add, this only applies to websites.

Comment: Thank you. Where do I go look for the references ? Does this look like the correct path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0` ?

Comment: I think it depends on where you have installed them... Look in the reference manager interface for the specified file path. Make sure that the reference you are trying to add is in that path. If not, reinstall it with the specified file path or, browse to the location of the installed reference.

If it really becomes a problem, I'd recommend taking a look at the NuGet package manager. Really makes it easy to add references and libs to your project.